# Finding MODE instead of MAX/AVG with a group by function mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by, average

I was using the following query, but while testing found that `MODE` gives me a better result than considering `MAX`.

```
SELECT MAX(rssi) AS rssii,beacon,receiver  
FROM readings 
WHERE created_datetime BETWEEN  '2018-11-29 09:46:10'  AND  '2018-11-29 10:58:50'
GROUP BY beacon,receiver;
```

I was able to get the mode of `RSSI` while only selecting the particular column I mean without any group by,

```
SELECT rssi,count(*) as occurs
FROM readings
GROUP BY `rssi` order by occurs desc
LIMIT 1;
```

but I am finding it hard to do the same for each group,

expected result format

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+
| rssii | beacon    |   receiver|
+-------+-----------+-----------+
|   -42 |       AAA |       XXX |
|   -49 |       AAA |       YYY |
|   -49 |       AAA |       ZZZ |
|   -44 |       BBB |       XXX |
|   -54 |       BBB |       YYY |
|   -52 |       BBB |       ZZZ |
|   -49 |       CCC |       XXX |
|   -42 |       CCC |       YYY |
|   -57 |       CCC |       ZZZ |
+-------+---------+-------------+
```

Can anyone please help....

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a simpler way to find MODE(S) of some values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646875/is-there-a-simpler-way-to-find-modes-of-some-values-in-mysql)

Comment: What MySQL version are you using ? There is simpler approach possible using Window/Analytic functions in MySQL 8.0.2 and above

Comment: @Madhur mysql 5.7. and Madhur the link u shared is simpler , I mean my problem s a bit different , cse I have to find the mode for each group of beacon,receiver

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: If still struggling, read the link shared by Strawberry in previous comment; edit the question to add some details. *Help us* If **you want help**

Comment: @fa06   added the sample output

Comment: @Madhur   edited the description

Comment: And where is the input data for your sample output. Sample input data must correspond to expected output

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem by first getting the count of `rssi` values per beacon/receiver pair like this:

```
SELECT beacon, receiver, rssi, COUNT(*) as occurs
FROM readings
GROUP BY beacon, receiver, rssi
```

Then to find the mode for each beacon/receiver pair you can use that as a subquery, joining it to a list of the maximum `occurs` values:

```
SELECT beacon, receiver, rssi, occurs 
FROM (SELECT beacon, receiver, rssi, COUNT(*) as occurs
      FROM readings
      GROUP BY beacon, receiver, rssi) r1
JOIN (SELECT beacon, receiver, rssi, MAX(occurs)
      FROM (SELECT beacon, receiver, rssi, COUNT(*) as occurs
            FROM readings
            GROUP BY beacon, receiver, rssi) r2
      GROUP BY beacon, receiver, rssi) r3
  ON r3.beacon = r1.beacon AND r3.receiver = r1.receiver AND r3.rssi = r1.rssi
```

Note that if there are multiple mode values for a beacon/receiver pair this will give you all of them. You may want to use `MAX(rssi)` in the initial select and `GROUP BY beacon, receiver` to restrict the result to one `rssi` value per pair i.e.

```
SELECT beacon, receiver, MAX(rssi), occurs 
FROM (SELECT beacon, receiver, rssi, COUNT(*) as occurs
      FROM readings
      GROUP BY beacon, receiver, rssi) r1
JOIN (SELECT beacon, receiver, rssi, MAX(occurs)
      FROM (SELECT beacon, receiver, rssi, COUNT(*) as occurs
            FROM readings
            GROUP BY beacon, receiver, rssi) r2
      GROUP BY beacon, receiver, rssi) r3
  ON r3.beacon = r1.beacon AND r3.receiver = r1.receiver AND r3.rssi = r1.rssi
GROUP BY beacon, receiver
```

Answer (score 1):

As like in many other complex problems, dynamic programming comes handy to solve this one and easy to understand also.

First declare two temporary variable in Mysql

```
set @mc1 = '', @rc1 = '';
```

Then use these as a temporary place holder and to iterate through the resultset.

```
select rssi,cr, mc,rc, @mc1:=mc,@rc1:=rc from (
SELECT rssi, count(rssi) cr,beacon AS mc,receiver AS rc
FROM readings
WHERE created_datetime BETWEEN  '2018-11-29 09:46:10'  AND  '2018-11-29 10:58:50'
GROUP BY readings.beacon ,readings.receiver, rssi order by mc,rc,cr desc
) p where (mc != @mc1 or rc != @rc1)
```

and I get what I wanted

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
| rssi | cr  | mc  | rc  | @mc1:=mc | @rc1:=rc |
+------+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------+
|  -53 | 127 | AAA | XXX    | AAA   | XXX |
|  -55 | 109 | AAA | YYYY   | AAA   | YYYY |
|  -52 | 194 | AAA | ZZZ    | AAA   | ZZZ |
|  -53 | 112 | BBB | XXX    | BBB   | XXX |
|  -48 | 218 | BBB | YYYY   | BBB   | YYYY |
|  -64 |  72 | BBB | ZZZ    | BBB   | ZZZ |
|  -47 | 151 | CCC| XXX     | CCC   | XXX |
|  -38 | 204 | CCC| YYYY    | CCC   | YYYY |
|  -53 | 120 | CCC| ZZZ     | CCC   | ZZZ |
|  -54 | 152 | DDD| XXX     | DDD   | XXX |
|  -62 |  80 | DDD| YYYY    | DDD   | YYYY |
|  -56 | 138 | DDD| ZZZ     | DDD   | ZZZ |
+------+-----+-----------+----------+
```

Comment: with this I can now solve my other problems easily. Thanks !